# Finding the closed form of $\prod _{n=0}^{\infty }\left(1\:-\:x^{2^n}+x^{2^{n+1}}\right)$

Tags: polynomials, closed-form, infinite-product

As far as I can tell this expression doesn't telescope. How would one go about this?

Comment: Consider a combinatorial representation (as a generating function)

Comment: @Winther Ah that makes sense, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that
$$(1 - x^{2^n} + x^{2^{n+1}})(1+x^{2^n}) = 1 + (x^{3})^{2^n}\implies \prod_{n\geq 0}(1 - x^{2^n} + x^{2^{n+1}}) = \frac{f(x^3)}{f(x)}$$
where $f(x) = \prod_{n\geq 0}(1+x^{2^n})$ so the problem reduces to evaluating $f(x)$. For this you can use
$$(1-x^{2^n})(1+x^{2^n}) = (1-x^{2^{n+1}}) \implies (1+x^{2^n}) = \frac{(1-x^{2^{n+1}})}{(1-x^{2^n})}$$
which we see will telescope when you take the product.

---

Another way is to notice that the partial products of the original series when multiplied with $(1+x+x^2)$ gives us
$$(1-x+x^2)\cdot (1+x+x^2) = 1 + x^2 + x^4$$
$$(1-x+x^2)(1-x^2+x^4)\cdot (1+x+x^2) = 1 + x^4 + x^8$$
$$(1-x+x^2)(1-x^2+x^4)(1-x^4+x^8)\cdot (1+x+x^2) = 1 + x^8 + x^{16}$$
which shows a pattern for the partial products that you can prove using induction.